# PyCharm /. VSCode - how to use global python installation

Tags: python, pycharm

Recently did a clean install of Linux Mint on an old laptop.

Tried writing a python script to use pyaudio. From inside PyCharm, I tried the usual method to add pyaudio using the project preferences screen, but that just kept "loading". When I tried to install it via pip inside a terminal in PyCharm, I get an error that it cannot create the wheel.

If I work 100% off the command line however, I am able to install pyaudio AND run the script without problems.

So, how can I get PyCharm to use my "default" python as per my command line - I tried changing the interpreter to the /usr/sbin/python3 , but it still does not detect the already installed library for pyaudio. So currently I can edit the file in PyCharm, but can only run it from command line...

Answer (score 0):

Open your project in PyCharm.
Go to File -> Settings (or PyCharm -> Preferences on Mac).
In the left-hand pane, select "Project: [your project name]" -> "Project Interpreter".
In the top-right corner, click the gear icon and select "Add".
In the "Add Python Interpreter" dialog, select "System Interpreter" and then select the path to your Python interpreter. On Linux Mint, this is usually located at /usr/bin/python3.
Click "OK" to save the changes.

Once you've added the system interpreter to PyCharm, it should be able to find the PyAudio library that you installed from the command line.

If PyCharm still can't find the PyAudio library, you can try refreshing the list of packages in the PyCharm package manager. To do this, go to File -> Settings -> "Project: [your project name]" -> "Project Interpreter", select the interpreter you just added, and then click the "Refresh" button.

If you continue to have problems, you can also try creating a virtual environment in PyCharm and installing PyAudio in that environment. This can help isolate your project's dependencies from other Python packages on your system. To create a virtual environment in PyCharm, go to File -> New Project, select "Pure Python", and then select "New environment".

Comment: That's exactly what I tried, and I cannot get PyCharm to pick up on the already installed Libraries, nor can I find any way to "re-install" the library from inside PyCharm to make it "see" it...